# Compile problems with native raspberry pi

Tags: gcc, compilation, compiler-errors, arm, raspberry-pi

**The problem**

We are trying to compile the spi_slave code on a raspberry pi. We used the native gcc compiler and the compile runs without any errors.

The problem is when I try to run the output:

/home/pi/spi_slave# ./build/output.elf
Segmentation fault

/home/pi/spi_slave# ./build/kernel.img
bash: ./build/kernel.img: cannot execute binary file

Tried to download the arm-none-eabi compiler from cambridge but it wont run:
/home/pi/spi_slave# ../arm-2008q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc
bash: ../arm-2008q3/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc: cannot execute binary file

**Sourcecode**

The code we are trying to compile is: http://tylernichols.me/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/raspberry_pi_bare_metal_spi_slave.zip

The only change we did was in the makefile, added a # in front of the ARMGNU var

```
#ARMGNU = arm-none-eabi
```

**Environement**

```
# uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.6.11+ #371 PREEMPT Thu Feb 7 16:31:35 GMT 2013 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

We have tried to find answers on google and stackoverflow for hours now without success. :/

Comment: It looks like *dwelch* (probably the same as on stack-overflow) has a newlib port for the Raspberry PI.  https://github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi/tree/master/newlib0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arm-none-eabi` is a non-linux compiler.  It is for *bare-metal* applications.  The difference is in the `C` library.  However, `gcc` is intimately linked to the `C` library for normal compiles.

Then there is the code.  It is not written for Linux.  It is written for a *bare-metal* application.  You need to load and run the code from the Raspberry-Pi boot loader (berryboot?) without Linux.

You can use the ARM Linux compiler to create code for a *bare-metal* application.  However, it is probably easier for you to find a **newlib** compiler that is targeted for the Raspberry Pi.  You can search for one on the web *or* try to build one yourself.

See: [How to build `gcc` for Raspberry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973020/cross-compilation-for-raspberry-pi-in-gcc-where-to-start) and [Bare-metal gcc](http://www.kunen.org/uC/gnu_tool.html).