# Xargo config for Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, rust, cross-compiling

I'm learning to build a simple bare metal program (without Linux OS) for Raspberry Pi (gen 1).

However, I don't know how to setup the cross-compiler under the hood of xargo. There are docs on [rust-cross](https://github.com/japaric/rust-cross) about RPI 2 but not about RPI 1.

Is there some example how to do it? I've tried several existing repos on github but all failed to compile.

[RPI-Kernel](https://github.com/osnr/rpi-kernel)
[IronKernel](https://github.com/sarjun/cs4414-ps4)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-compilation for Raspberry Pi in GCC. Where to start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973020/cross-compilation-for-raspberry-pi-in-gcc-where-to-start)